# Generating CRM4 WSDL from instance

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, wsdl, dynamics-crm-4

How can I go about obtaining the latest WSDL files from a CRM4 deployment?

Currently we have a deployment in place on a hosted solution where there are two WSDL files available via Settings > Customization > Download Web Service Description Files

From this location there are two files available:
- CrmService.asmx
- MetadataService.asmx

If I attempt to click on these files then it opens web URLs as follows:
- http://be-crm4.domain.co.uk/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx
- http://be-crm4.domain.co.uk/MSCrmServices/2007/MetadataService.asmx?WSDL

However upon looking at the visual studio C# coded connector tool that interacts with the current CRM instance that a previous developer has done I can see that he has reference to 3 WSDL.

- CrmService
- CRMMetaService
- CrmDiscoveryService

The Discovery service URL is as follows:
- http://be-sql-live01/MSCRMServices/2007/AD/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx

We are currently in the process of moving our server to another server and I am testing the webservice component of this but as there have been changes I want to regenerate the WSDL files.

How can I save the wsdl files from the browser? How can I find the discovery URL of the webservices as only 2 of these seem to be appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bit late but maybe someone will find this helpfull.
On on-permise instane using AD the address for discovery service is:

```
http[s]://<hostname>[:port]/mscrmservices/2007/AD/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx
```

On IFD instance:

```
http[s]://<hostname>[:port]/mscrmservices/2007/IFD/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx
```

You can get WSDL by adding ?WSDL on the end of webservice address for example:

```
http[s]://<hostname>[:port]/mscrmservices/2007/AD/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx?WSDL
```